# Increase retrieving perf python appengine with memcache

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hello I want to know if in the appengine env the things I did is usefull
Because I don't know why this page is very slow.

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    description = db.TextProperty()    
    carac = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)



class FoosPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    foos =  memcache.get("all-foos")
    if foos is None:
        foos = Foo.all()
        size = foo.count()
    else :
        size = len(foo)

    foosTab=[]
    for i in range(size) :
        foosTab.insert(i,foos[i])
        memcache.set("all-foos", foosTab, 60)
    template_values = {
        'foos': foos
            }
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../templates/', 'foos.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

Comment: Slow relative to what?  Can you provide some timing data for this vs. something similar?

Comment: how many objects are in foo?  are you running this on your dev machine or is it deployed?  Does it go faster if you do a fetch(1000) right before you do the call to foo.count()?

Comment: Hi very slow, for about 50 object 4sec,something strange In local it is faster,
@peter I will test for the fetch

Comment: Have you used appstats? It's designed to answer exactly this sort of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the `memcache.set()` inside the loop. That's a lot of unnecessary traffic to the `memcache` service. Do it once, after the loop.

Further, the way you have that coded, there's no need for establishing `size`.

```
foosTab = []
for foo in foos:
    foosTab.append(foo)
```

or, more idiomatically

```
foosTab = [foo for foo in foos]
```

That'll save you doing a separate `count()`.

Comment: +1, good answer. Also, i usually store the entity keys instead of the hole elements.

Comment: Iterating over query results is a bad idea - it results in one RPC call per 20 results.

Answer (score 2):

This block of code:

```
foos =  memcache.get("all-foos")
if foos is None:
    foos = Foo.all()
    size = foo.count()
else :
    size = len(foo)

foosTab=[]
for i in range(size) :
    foosTab.insert(i,foos[i])
    memcache.set("all-foos", foosTab, 60)
```

Can be replaced with this (much simpler) code:

```
foos = memcache.get("all-foos")
if not foos:
  foos = Foo.all.fetch(1000) # At most 1000 foos
  memcache.set("all-foos", foos, 60)
```

Specifically, it avoids the unnecessary call to `count()` (which issues an expensive RPC for something you'll find out anyway when you fetch the result), it does a single fetch call instead of iterating over the results and fetching in batches of 20, and it only calls memcache set (once!) if it had to fetch the list in the first place.